# Navigation bar is missing in Tabbar based application sometimes when application entered in to background

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have the tab bar based application and each tab is a navigation based viewcontroller sometimes when my application entered in to background, and it comes back to foreground i am missing the navigation bar in the viewcontroller.

Why it happening like this?

Comment: @jbat100: Hi, the problem is i have entry module that returns the viewcontroller is created by library and i will create the navigationcontroller and set this viewcontroller as the rootviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the UINavigationController's navigationBarHidden property is set to NO. If it is check the frame of the UINavigationBar (and all other relevant UIView properties like hidden, alpha etc).